# Scout Laravel Algolia search too queries

Tags: laravel, search, eloquent, algolia, laravel-scout

I'm using Laravel scout with Algolia search.

I have this eloquent relation:

```
public function doctors()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Doctor::class, 'doctor_id');
}
```

Here I get results by Algolia search:

```
  $doctors = DoctorInfo::search($this->search)
                                ->with([
                                'typoTolerance' => true,
  ])
  ->paginate(10);
```

I get a lot of single queries:

```
select * from `doctors` where `doctors`.`id` = 131 limit 1
select * from `doctors` where `doctors`.`id` = 141 limit 1
select * from `doctors` where `doctors`.`id` = 191 limit 1
....
```

How can I get an eloquent relation using "whereIn" instead "where"?

thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

Solved in this way.

```
$doctors = DoctorInfo::search($this->search)
                                ->with([
                                'typoTolerance' => true,
  ])
   ->query(function ($builder) {
            $builder->with('doctors');
  })
  ->paginate(10);
```

My query is unique now like this:

```
select * from `doctors` where `doctors`.`id` in (12, 88, 107, 108, 111, 131, 168, 170, 175, 181)
```

Thanks for all.